# Emptying an <ol> and repopulating it in JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, html-lists

I'm trying to remove the li elements from an ol and then put new li elements back into it. I know it sounds like it should be a fairly simple task with .empty() and .append(), but...

When I don't attempt to remove my li elements, inputting works just fine. When I do attempt to clear it, either nothing is removed and input works normally or everything is removed and I can't input things at all. I've looked at the JQuery documentation and I think I'm misunderstanding either the use of .empty() or one of the other methods...

HTML:

```
<input id="btn-add" type="submit" />
<ol id='listOfStuff'>
<!-- elements are inserted here -->
</ol>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function addToList(thing1, number1){
$('#listOfStuff').append('<li>'+thing1+' - '+number1+'</li>');}

function printList(){ //Clear the data, then reprint it
//What I think is the main problem: 
$('#listOfStuff').children.remove();//stops the input if I use it
$('#listOfStuff').empty(); //has no effect if I use it
$('#listOfStuff').clear(); //does what it should--not what I'm looking for, however
$('#listOfStuff').detatch();//stops input if I use it

addToList("Things", 42);}

$('#btn-add').click(function(){
//... 
//Other stuff which works just fine and isn't part of this question 
//...    
printList();
    }

});
```

Edit: Added Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/z6LqX/1/

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle of what you tried?

Comment: You should move you functions outside `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Ah, why should the functions be outside of document.ready?

Comment: Beacause whatever you out inside gets executed when dom ready. If what to get that functions executed just put `call_to_my_func();` but the definition of `call_to_my_func()` put it outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help you?

```
function addToList(thing1, number1)
{
    $('#listOfStuff').append('<li>' + thing1 + ' - ' + number1 + '</li>');
}

function clearList()
{
    $('#listOfStuff').empty();
}

$('#btn-add').click(function()
{
    clearList();
    addToList("Things", 42);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scX97/)

Comment: Is there a benefit to putting $('#listOfStuff').empty(); inside a function and calling the function instead of just using the statement itself?

Comment: Not really, I just wrote it that way following your example and for you to see how to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: Ah, okay.  Looking at your fiddle, that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Thanks. I'm trying to get that working in my own fiddle now, but it's not working. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're misunderstanding, you're mentioning the right methods. I can't tell what you've actually tried or are trying to do since you gave several different examples:

`empty` clears all child html elements. For an `ol` it would wipe all `li`s

`append` adds a new dom element, so you're using it properly

```
$('#listOfStuff').append('<li>Text 1</li>');
$('#btn-add').click(function(e){
    $('#listOfStuff').empty();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRP2c/)

Comment: I've tried all 4 of the examples I gave (not at the same time, of course!), and none of them worked the way I wanted to. I was expecting the first two I gave, .children.remove() and .empty(), to be the way that I should've done things. In my actual code I do use a for loop and an array, but that really shouldn't have affected anything.

Comment: What is your actual goal? If I understand more about the intended result I can clarify my answer

Comment: My goal is to take input and print it out onto the page in a sorted list format. When each element is submitted, I want it to be sorted-- so I'm using the js array to sort and then printing out the array. In order to avoid printing repeats, I need to clear the li elements first. Everything in the array works just fine according to my .alert() statements, the only problem is when I try to clear the li elements.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, the empty method will work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/z6LqX/4/

Comment: I'm trying to both clear the list and then repopulate it in the same button-click/function. That's why I have both the .empty() and the.addToList() functions in the .click() function

Comment: That works too. The fiddle won't appear to do anything because I repopulate with the same data but the method works. http://jsfiddle.net/z6LqX/6/